# prefix and postfix increment

Tags: c++, c++11

I am new to this site and I don't know where to look for this particular type of problem. I am not taking a course and was just playing around with Visual Studio, some code and ran into this problem.
Can someone help me with the following:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int v = 0;
int w = 0;

cout << v << v++ << endl;
cout << w;
cout << w++;
cout << endl;

//Testing with something else.
cout << "Hello " << "there." << endl;
cout << "Hello ";
cout << "there.";
cout << endl;

return 0;

}
```

The following should be the same right?

```
  cout << v << v++ << endl;
  cout << w;
  cout << w++;
  cout << endl;
```

The first line should print out "00" since the first number is what v has been assigned and the following number is what appears with v++ (v has been incremented by 1 but since its post we cannot see it just yet). Yet I get "10".
When I work with the lines that involve w (which should work the same due to the same initialized value), I get "00", which is about right.
Shouldn't the lines be the same? 
When I work with the code following the comment, which is similar to the code involving v and w

```
//Testing with something else.
cout << "Hello " << "there." << endl;
cout << "Hello ";
cout << "there.";
cout << endl;
```

I get "Hello there." and "Hello there.". Identical.

Is there something obvious that I am missing?

Many thanks,

David

Comment: As the above link explains, this is undefined behavior because of sequence points.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points

Comment: This is because of the sequence points of the c++ compiler.

Comment: I see. Sorry for the duplicate and many thanks for the assist.